# what is the best way to parse such a url in android

Tags: java, android

I have this two kinds of url:

```
www.test.com/#!search/keyword/cat=52400005/
```

and

```
www.test.com/#!search/keyword/cat=52400005
```

I want to extract the `keyword` and `cat` from this kind string (`keyword` is variable and `cat` is followed by `=`).

How can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can split the string on the character "/" and then split substrings on "=". If the position of the words are always the same it is easy to extract the words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will give you that

```
^www.test.com/#!search/(.+)/cat=(.+)/$

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^www.test.com/#!search/(.+)/cat=(.+)/$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(url);

while(m.find()) {
    String keyword = m.group(1);
    String cat = m.group(2);
}
```

keyword is the first group, cat is the second.

Comment: Thank you, but how to use `regex` in java / android. Could you pleas give me some sample codes?

Comment: Thank you, that almost perfect, but how to match this case: `www.test.com/#!search/keyword/cat=52400005`, there is not `/` at last postion.

Comment: Finally, I use this `#!search/(.+)/cat=([a-zA-z0-9]+)` to extract the values. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.test.com/#!search/keyword/cat=52400005/");        
    String ref = url.getRef();

    List<String> segments = Uri.parse(ref).getPathSegments();


    String keyWord = segments.get(1);
    String cat = segments.get(2).substring(4);
```

EDIT: Tested and working.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but `#!search/keyword/cat=52400005/` is not part of `Path`, it is in the anchor tag.

Comment: Oops, didn't see that. Fixed now.

Comment: This solution is also working, but I've ticked the other answer, thank you, you are so kind.